# Ошибка при входе на страницу "админки"

Tags: java, java-ee, jsp, сервлеты

Код страницы для перехода на страницу админки:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Вход</title>
</head>


<body>
    <h3>Вы удачно вошли! Добро пожаловать, ${login}</h3>
    <p>
        <a href="site.jsp">На страницу создания своего сайта</a><br>
        <!--<a href="adminka.jsp">На страницу админки</a><br>-->
        <a href="AdminServlet">На страницу админки</a><br>
    </p>
</body>
```

Код сервлета "админки":

```
@WebServlet(name = "AdminServlet", urlPatterns = {"/AdminServlet"})
public class AdminServlet extends HttpServlet 
{
static String loginuser;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    HttpSession httpSession = req.getSession(true);
    loginuser = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("loginuser");

    String folderName = (String) httpSession.getAttribute("loginuser");
    File folder = new File("/home/torin/NetBeansProjects/CMS/"
            + folderName);
    File[] files = folder.listFiles();
    req.setAttribute("files", files);
    req.getRequestDispatcher("/adminka.jsp").forward(req, resp);
}
}
```

код страницы "админки":

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Админка</title>
</head>


<body>
    <h1>Админка пользователя - <%= session.getAttribute("login") %></h1>
    <p>
        <c:forEach var="file" items="${files}">
            <c:out value = "${file}"/><br>
            <a href="change.jsp">Изменение страницы</a><br>
            <a href="openpage.jsp">Открыть страницу</a>
        </c:forEach>
    </p>
</body>
```

При входе на страницу "админки" возникает ошибка HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

Comment: Чем war собираете?

Comment: и в какой контейнер кладете?

Comment: <Context path="/CMS" 
                   docBase="/home/torin/NetBeansProjects/CMS/target/CMS-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"/> прописал в server.xml сборка идет с помощью maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию Tomcat не укомплектован JSTL. Либо скачайте [jstl-1.2.jar](http://central.maven.org/maven2/jstl/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar) и положите в lib сервера, либо добавьте в pom.xml вашего приложения:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>jstl</groupId>
  <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже сделал)