# При попытке подключить jstl получаю ошибку Java EE

Tags: java-ee, servlet, jstl

При попытке использовать jstl в проекте получаю ошибку при запуске сервлета. 
Уже что только не пробовал: и явно подключал war, и менял group-id у jstl в pom,
и добавлял/удалял WEB-INF с web.xml (у меня версия сервлета 3.1 )
Кто знает в чем может быть причина?

Вот сама ошибка:

```
HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
type Exception report

message The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:117)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTLDLocation(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:325)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:154)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:419)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:484)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1421)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:242)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:102)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:660)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    ui.CarListServlet.service(CarListServlet.java:31)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.85 logs.
```

jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Choose your car</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Car list</h1>
<h3>Choose a rental car</h3>

<c:forEach items="${list}" var="car">
   <tr>
    <td> ${car.getId()}</td>
       <td> ${car.getModel()}</td>

   </tr>
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

pom xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>groupId</groupId>
    <artifactId>AvtoProjectEE</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при входе на страницу "админки"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/808904/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%83-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev пробовал. не оно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

500 ошибка в данном случае говорит о том, что мой Tomcat Server не видит библиотеки jstl. Поэтому мне необходимо добавить в сервер ее самостоятельно, для этого переходим: `File -> Project Structure -> Artifact и в левом Листе ищем наш jstl -> Двойной клик и Apply`. Готово!